# Most "poetic" way to normalize value into an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

#### Edit

A lot of people are suggesting `Array.isArray()...`, which I disagree with. It's actually what I moved away from. The simple reason is that it gets ugly with longer var names. We may as well leave a comment instead. But I'm sure there's a better way...

```
longerVariableName = [longerVariableName].flat() //normalizes

longerVariableName = Array.isArray(longerVariableName) ? longerVariableName : [longerVariableName]
```

---

#### Original

Not sure if "poetic" is the right word; but I often have variables of type `string | string[]`. I want to normalize them to just `[string]` to make it easier to work with.

The shortest way I can think of is `[var].flat()`

i.e. if it's not an array, turn it to an array. If it's already an array, leave it alone.

The problem with the above method however is that I feel its not very easy to understand, especially for others. I could leave a comment, but it kind of negates the point of the brevity.

Does anybody have any other suggestions?

Comment: Write *clear, readable* code, don't try to look tricky or smart or poetic. `Array.isArray(arg) ? arg : [arg]`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I would upvote that as an answer. Just to explain why: there are competing goals as far as readability goes. 1. less code to read, 2. obviousness of the code. If you have a very common pattern, then goal 1 is achieved simply because the common pattern becomes so easy to spot that you barely have to "read" it at all. So a very obvious, clear one-liner that is easily spotted and mentally parsed is usually the best option.

Comment: Maybe "idiomatic"? Either way, agree that @CertainPerformance is the way to go

Comment: @user1543574 If you have some globally accessible location to store it, you could name a function `asArr` and use that everywhere. If you are using it a lot, it kind of doesn't matter what you use, so long as it is consistent, because once the reader figures out what it means once, it applies to all instances. Presumably you are putting this at the top of many functions?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```js
[].concat(arrayOrString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Write clear, readable code, don't try to look tricky or smart or poetic.

```
Array.isArray(arg) ? arg : [arg]
```

That's super easy to read. It *could* be made shorter, but that would come at the expense of understandability, and so wouldn't be worth it IMO. Writing good software isn't a code-golf competition.